# How to use $(this) for File Reader image src?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I am trying to get a preview of selected photos and the code below works but when I select a second photo, the src of the first one also changes. How can I have it so only the previewPhoto that is being appended changes its src?

```
    $(function(){
        $("#photo").change(showPreview);
    });
    function showPreview(e) {
        var $input = $(this);
        var inputFiles = this.files;
        if(inputFiles == undefined || inputFiles.length == 0) return;
        var inputFile = inputFiles[0];

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(event) {
            $("<div class='preview'></div>").append("<img class='previewPhoto'/>").appendTo("#previewBox");
            $('.previewPhoto').attr('src', event.target.result);
        };
        reader.onerror = function(event) {
            alert("ERROR: " + event.target.error.code);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(inputFile);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `.previewPhoto` as selector otherwise you'll change others too.
You can append it with it's `src` like the following.

```
$("<div class='preview'></div>")
    .append("<img class='previewPhoto' src='" + event.target.result + "'/>")
    .appendTo("#previewBox");
```

Answer (score 0):

Cache the object in a variable:

```
reader.onload = function(event) {
    var $previewPhoto = $("<img class='previewPhoto'/>");
    $("<div class='preview'></div>").append($previewPhoto).appendTo("#previewBox");
    $previewPhoto.attr('src', event.target.result);
};
```

This way the variable will hold a pointer to the actual object; rather than traversing the DOM for it. This is also a key factor for performance when using JQuery selectors.